# Get tracks for each returned album is not working for some artists

Tags: python

I'm getting the top artists from a specific country, albums of that artists and tracks of that albums from lastfm api. I'm getting the artists and albums without errors, but in the tracks it appears:

```
for album in album_response['album']['tracks']['track']: KeyError: 'album'
```

The issue seems that is because some artists have spaces in the name, so I replace it with "+" also with "%2b" but none solution is working it always appears the error above.

```
chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
chosen = '+'.join(artists[i]['name'].lower().split())
chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "%2B")
```

The track part where is the error :

```
tracks = {}
for i,v in albums.items():
    artist = albums[i]['artist'].replace(" ","+")
    name = albums[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    album_response_data = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&format=json&api_key='+api_key+'&artist='+artist+'&album='+name)
    album_response = album_response_data.json()

    print(album_response)      
    for album in album_response['album']['tracks']['track']:


        title = album['name']
        number = album['@attr']['rank']
        duration = album['duration']

        tracks[ID] = {}
        tracks[ID]['title'] = title
        tracks[ID]['number'] = number
        tracks[ID]['artist'] = albums[i]['artist']
        tracks[ID]['album'] = albums[i]['name']
        tracks[ID]['albumID'] = albums[i]['ID']
        tracks[ID]['duration'] = duration

        ID += 1
```

Minimum working exemple:

```
import requests

api_key = "b088cbedecd40b35dd89e90f55227ac2"
ID= 0

#Get artists from specific country

artists = {}
for i in range(2, 3):
    artists_response = requests.get(
        'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&format=json&page=' + str(i) + '&api_key=' + api_key)
    artists_data = artists_response.json()
    for artist in artists_data["topartists"]["artist"]:

        name = artist["name"]

        url = artist["url"]
        #if ID > 3 continue
        artists[ID] = {}
        artists[ID]['ID'] = ID
        artists[ID]['name'] = name

        ID += 1


#Get TopAlbums info from above artists

albums = {}
for i, v in artists.items():
    chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    topalbums_response = requests.get(
        'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.gettopalbums&format=json&artist=' + chosen + '&api_key=' + api_key + '&limit=5')
    albums_data = topalbums_response.json()

    for album in albums_data['topalbums']['album']:
        name = album["name"]
        url = album["url"]

        albums[ID] = {}
        albums[ID]['ID'] = ID
        albums[ID]['artist'] = artists[i]['name']
        albums[ID]['artistID'] = artists[i]['ID']
        albums[ID]['name'] = name
        albums[ID]['url'] = url

        ID += 1

#Get tracks info of the above albums

tracks = {}
for i,v in albums.items():
    artist = albums[i]['artist'].replace(" ","+")
    name = albums[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    album_response_data = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&format=json&api_key='+api_key+'&artist='+artist+'&album='+name)
    album_response = album_response_data.json()


    for album in album_response['album']['tracks']['track']:  

            title = album['name']

            number = album['@attr']['rank']
            duration = album['duration']

            tracks[ID] = {}

            tracks[ID]['trackID'] = ID

            tracks[ID]['title'] = title
            tracks[ID]['number'] = number
            tracks[ID]['artist'] = albums[i]['artist']
            tracks[ID]['album'] = albums[i]['name']
            tracks[ID]['albumID'] = albums[i]['ID']
            tracks[ID]['duration'] = duration

            ID += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the album_response in the case where you get the error is `{'error': 6, 'message': 'Album not found', 'links': []}`

I added a line to print out the name of the artist and album that is being processed in the loop, and I see that the artist is Ed Sheeran but there is no associated album.

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I will tell you that you need to fix up your looping variables.  In python, variables are scoped within functions, but not within control structures.  You have nested loops which are both using `i` as a variable in the loop.  This will usually cause conflicts as the inner loop advances `i` and those advances are seen by the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with record key 19 in your albums dictionary:

> 19: {'ID': 19,   'artist': 'Ed Sheeran',   'artistID': 3,   'image':
>   'https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/174s/d08fbb920e514f5c893d95552379d3fc.png',
>   'name': '+',   'url': 'https://www.last.fm/music/Ed+Sheeran/%252B'}

Note the name of the album is "+" a plus sign.

You need to urlencode "+" to %2B
or do a replace "+" with %2B.

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&format=json&api_key=b088cbedecd40b35dd89e90f55227ac2&artist=Ed+Sheeran&album=%2B

Otherwise you are getting back 
'message': 'Album not found'....

Comment: Thanks, but I add this "        if(album['name'] ==  'Ed+Sheeran'): continue
" before "title = album['name']" to test but appears the same issue.

Comment: @OzzyW you are going to have this problem with all signle character ablums that are special characters.  Ed Sheeran has a few.  Good luck with data wrangling.

Comment: Thanks. But there are other that also have spaces before that artist and they work, the error dont appears.

Comment: The Rolling Stones also have spaces and it works: http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=therollingstones&api_key=b088cbedecd40b35dd89e90f55227ac2&format=json. Do you know why?